# Accurate time on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, datetime

Is there an  way to get a time very precisely in iPhone.? Currently i am trying with the `ios` `NTp client` [Here](http://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp/) . I am getting almost **600 milliseconds** difference while comparing with different divices . Even i am not worrying about the accurate time like `ntp` , I want to show same time with `milliseconds` in different devices.

Comment: Are you forming the date from a dateString send from Server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490537/gmt-time-on-iphone

Comment: Yes .I am getting the time from different ntp server right now .

Comment: The ios-ntp client notes that it does not fully implement the NTP protocol and does not intend to achieve much more than ~ 1s accuracy. If you want greater accuracy, you'll probably need to use a full ntp client or implement your own. It's a very challenging problem; I'm not aware of an existing solution. I would probably start by extending the ntp-ios code, since it already does part of the work.

Comment: Thanks Rob .. Please let me know if you find any solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this NTP client library for iOS: https://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp/

Source: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269532/network-time-protocol-for-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

This is simple way to do this go through it :-

```
 + (NSDate *) GMTNow
 { 
  NSDate *sourceDate = [NSDate date];
  NSTimeZone* currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
  NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMT];

  [sourceDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:currentGMTOffset];

  return sourceDate;
  }
```

Comment: Is it depends on system time .?

Comment: No its depends on your location and universal time. It always give exact time rather your system time changed.

Comment: Thanks for your replay ..Still its not working for me .Its getting 3-4 second difference in different device :(

Comment: Can you tell me for which purpose you required such precise timing. Please elaborate. If answer is helpful to upvote it.

Comment: want to trigger some event in precise time ( playing audio ,video kind of stuff ) in different devices . In case of audio playing in different devices user can easily identify the difference .

Comment: Means you want to trigger a event on multiple device which run that event simultaneously, I am getting you right r not.

Comment: Yeah .you are right .but the start time of the event in all devices should be accurate .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28897/discussion-between-arpit-kumar-and-sat-v-can-shake-the-world)

Comment: `-addTimeInterval:` is deprecated, should use `-dateByAddingTimeInterval:`