# iPhone - Problem with NSDate to get time interval according to current time zone

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I am using NSDate to get the NSTimeInterval according to current time zone.
But I'm getting information related to UTC.
I'm using methods like "dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow" and "dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970"
How can I get time interval as per my time zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in a fair bit of detail here.

[How to convert time to the time zone of the iPhone device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081647/how-to-convert-time-to-the-timezone-of-the-iphone-device/1082179#1082179)

You might also want to check this out

[Using TimeZones](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html)

Answer (score -1):

If both are NSDates then you could do :

```
//calculate the time difference in seconds, that is absolute and does not depend in time zones :)
double timeDiffInSecs = [date1 timeIntervalSince1970] - [date2 timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Comment: I just want current time interval for current time zone and not UTC