# Convert date and time to local date and time format

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I am facing issue while converting date and time in device's current (Local) date and time.
Am getting date in format 2013-04-03 01:07:56 +0000 from API and I want to convert this date in local date and time format and display. Can anyone please suggest me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Just set the timeZone in the dateFormatter, This code is enough

```
NSString *dateString = @"24 08 2011 09:45PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy hh:mma"];
NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"BST"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:sourceTimeZone];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

The dateFromString will now have the date 24 08 2011 08:45PM(GMT).. Then to convert this to string with local time just code the following,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy hh:mma"];
NSString *stringFromDAte = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateString];
```

Comment: Thanks Kirti,But I want to show date format according to device format. Here my app supports localization also.

Comment: @Vijay Follow this URl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081647/how-to-convert-time-to-the-timezone-of-the-iphone-device