# How to convert server TimeZone in to Device TimeZone

Tags: iphone, ios, timezone

My server gives date like this

```
07/22/2013 06:13:04 PM UTC +05:30
```

I want to convert it to Device time zone.Like if my Device time zone is `Local Time Zone (Asia/Kolkata (GMT+05:30) offset 19800)` than what this date will look like

Searched on Google and try so much code but not have any luck. plz help me.

Comment: I guess this would help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268509/convert-utc-nsdate-to-local-timezone-objective-c

Comment: Have a look at this also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081647/how-to-convert-time-to-the-timezone-of-the-iphone-device?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Your dateFormat does not match the format of your date string. Read about the [Unicode Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
And after that try `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"`

But I think you try to do something wrong anyway.
A NSDate is a point in time, it is the same for every place in the world. You don't need to calculate a new NSDate just because your source is in a different timezone.

Use the dateFormat from above and compare it directly to a different NSDate.

Probably something like this:

```
NSString *serverTime = @"2012-01-11T06:17:39+0000";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
NSDate* sourceDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:serverTime];
if (!sourceDate) {
    NSLog(@"Wrong NSDateFormatter format!");
}
else {
    NSDate *date24HoursAgo = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-(24*60*60)];
    NSLog(@"%@", sourceDate);
    NSLog(@"%@", date24HoursAgo);
    if ([sourceDate compare:date24HoursAgo] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        NSLog(@"Timestamp from server is older than 24 hours.");
    }
}
```